# Global maximum of function

Tags: probability, maxima-minima, global-optimization

The function $\sum_{j=1}^{N} w_{j}.\log y_{j}$ , subject to the constraints

$y_{j} \ge 0$ and $\sum_{j=1}^{N} y_{j} = 1$ , attains a global maximum at the single point

$$y_{j} = \frac{w_{j}}{\sum_{i=1}^{N} w_{i}} , j = 1,2,3, ..., N $$

How do you prove this?

Comment: You can maximize $\prod\limits_{j=1}^n y_j^{w_j}$ under the  condition $\sum\limits_{j=1}^{N} y_{j} = 1$ .

Comment: Do you know the method of [Lagrange multipliers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier)?

Comment: I will look into Lagrange multipliers. Thanks for the direction.

Comment: Feel free to ask if something is unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$f =\sum_{i=1}^n w_i\log\left(\frac{y_i}{w_i}\right) + \sum_{i=1}^n w_i\log\left(w_i\right)$$

The function $\log x$ is concave (as the second derivarive is equal to $-1/x^2$ and so negative). It suffices then to apply the [Jensen's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality#Finite_form):

$$\sum_{i=1}^n w_i\log\left(\frac{y_i}{w_i}\right)\le\left(\sum_{i=1}^n w_i  \right)\cdot \log\left(\underbrace{\sum_{i=1}^n \left( w_i\cdot \frac{y_i}{w_i}\right)}_{=\sum_{i=1}^ny_i=1} /\left(\sum_{i=1}^n w_i\right)\right) =-\left(\sum_{i=1}^n w_i\right)\cdot\log \left(\sum_{i=1}^n w_i\right)$$
We deduce
$$\color{red}{f \le -\left(\sum_{i=1}^n w_i\right)\cdot\log \left(\sum_{i=1}^n w_i\right) + \sum_{i=1}^n w_i\log\left(w_i\right)}$$

The equality occurs if and only if $\frac{y_1}{w_1}=...= \frac{y_n}{w_n} \iff y_i = w_i/ \sum_{j=1}^n w_j$ for $i=1,...,n$.

Comment: I see that y1/w1 = y2/w2 ... is immediately implying that yi = wi/sum(wj). But I do not get why the equality holds "only" for yi/wi = constant. Plugging yi/wi=constant into the first term of function f , is supposed to zero it. I could not work it out to zero.

Comment: @AnanthaKrishnan It was a typo. I corrected it.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It is quite easy to visualize Jensen's inequality, which fundamentally states for a convex function g, g(E[x]) >= E[g(x)]. If we put a 1/n on both sides of the inequality, it makes sense for me, starting with g=wi*log(yi/wi). From smartly splitting the function to two and then applying Jensen's inequality, the answer is brillitant